# how to check if checkbox selected, and excute the necessary queries to update the corresponding tables?

Tags: php, mysql

HTML

```
<label for="wall_category">Wall Category:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="wallpaper"> Wallpaper
    <input type="checkbox" name="photography"> Photography
```

PHP

```
//obtains last insert id
    $wallId = mysql_insert_id();
    echo $wallId;
```

I have `categories` table in my database in which the following data is stored:

```
category_id  category_name
1             Wallpaper
2             Photography
```

and I have another table called `wall_categories` in which:

```
wall_id (P, F)    category_id (P, F)
```

After getting the wall_id from last_insert_id, I want to check what category among the two is checked. For example, `Wallpaper` checkbox is checked, since the `category_id` is `1`, I want to store that `category_id` along with whatever the `wall_id` will be to my `wall_categories` table. So my table will become (lets say `wall_id` is `16`)

```
wall_id (P, F)    category_id (P, F)
 16                 1
```

And one last thing to add since Categories are checkboxes, when both are selected, I want to add both to my `wall_categories` table so my `wall_categories` table would become:

```
wall_id (P, F)    category_id (P, F)
     16                 1
     16                 2
```

I was trying some workarounds, but I'm still a rookie in PHP. Would like to ask your help on how to do this. Thanks! (The script will just be used internally.)

Comment: what is the process you want?

Comment: by process, you mean?

Comment: did you want to insert the categories to your database? or how?

Comment: the `categories` table is already in my database. I want to insert the ids of the both, the category and wall_id to insert into my `wall_categories` table.

Comment: Ya, so you need a process to make it, right?

Comment: I think you should change your input name to a same name and make it has different value.

Comment: yes, I want to update `wall_categories` table.

Comment: didn't get what you said..

Comment: wait a moment, i will write an answer..

Comment: Is your `wall_id` automatically generated  or manually defined  ?

Comment: automatically generated in another table. But it will always be INT (1, 2, 3 ...and so on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <label for="category">Wall Category:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1"> Wallpaper
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2"> Photography
</form>
```

If you want to proceed checkboxes input, i suggest you to do it as the script above. `category[]` would be an array that could contain values such as `1` and `2` (your category id).
So you have to parse it in server side(PHP) before you insert it into database. if you set the `wall_id` column value automatically generated you will get some errors, because `wall_id` would be different with previous `wall_id`. So i suggest you to set it automatic but manually defined(didn't get my words? I'll explain it).

Here's the PHP :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database_name");
//First get the category from input
$checked = $_REQUEST['category']; // it's an array

//--------get last
    //Then you have to get the last wall_id from your wall_categories table
    //and add it 1 (+1)
    $q1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT MAX(wall_id) as last_wall_id from wall_categories"); // get last wall_id
    $last = mysqli_fetch_array($q1);
    $next_wall_id = $last['last_wall_id']+1;//+1 last wall_id for next wall_id
//-------end of get last

foreach($checked as $cat){
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO wall_categories (wall_id, category_id) values ('$next_wall_id','$cat') ");
}
?>
```

If your `wall_id` comes from another table, please skip `get last` step. and remove/change the `$next_wall_id` by the `wall_id` variable that you get from another table.
That's all if you want to do it. Any question? found some errors? comment it below :D

Comment: I think I need your help with this as well. haha. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20109823/3002948

Answer (score 1):

The code that worked very well for me, used last_insert_id instead since I'm sure that the most recent id is what I need to insert to my wall_categories table. Thanks a lot @Oki Erie Rinaldi!!

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database_name");
//First get the category from input
$checked = $_REQUEST['category']; // it's an array

$wallId = mysqli_insert_id($con); //retrieves the last ID.

foreach($checked as $cat){
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO wall_categories (wall_id, category_id) values ('$wallId','$cat') ");
}
?>
```